# How to handle exceptions in onError method of Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

My application crash when I logout from Firebase. I checked the logcat and it shows me the following stack trace.

```
 io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.Throwable: Permission denied
                                                   at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
                                                   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:74)
                                                   at messenger.tarang.com.messenger.allusers.AllUsers$loadUsers$1$1.onCancelled(AllUsers.kt:78)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzehy.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Permission denied
                                                   at messenger.tarang.com.messenger.allusers.AllUsers$loadUsers$1$1.onCancelled(AllUsers.kt:78) 
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzehy.zzbyc(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

Here is the code where the problem arises.

```
Observable.create<DataSnapshot>{ emitter ->
        databaseReference
                ?.child("Users")
                ?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
                        if(!emitter.isDisposed){
                               emitter.onError(Throwable(p0.message))
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

                    }
                    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

                    }
                    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
                        if(!emitter.isDisposed)
                        emitter.onNext(p0!!)
                    }
                    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {

                    }
                })
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : Observer<DataSnapshot>{
                override fun onComplete() {

                }

                override fun onNext(t: DataSnapshot) {
                        val userModel = t.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
                        userModel?.uid = t.key
                        userAdapter?.addData(userModel!!)
                }
                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                compositeDisposable?.add(d)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
```

Below is my Account Settings class where i am performing logout action.If i comment `emitter.onError()`in above code then i don't get any exceptions.

```
class AccountSettings internal constructor(): AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
var toolbar : Toolbar ?= null
var toolbar_text : TextView ?= null
var logout_text : TextView ?= null
var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.account_settings)
    initialize()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    logout_text?.setOnClickListener(this)
}

 fun initialize(){
     firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    logout_text = findViewById(R.id.logout_text)
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar_text = toolbar?.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text1)
    toolbar_text?.setText("Account Settings")
    toolbar_text?.visibility= View.VISIBLE
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}

 fun logout() {
    try {
        firebaseAuth?.signOut()
        displayMessage("logout successfully")
        goToMainActivity()
    }
    catch(ex : Exception){
        ex.printStackTrace()
        displayMessage("you are not connected to Internet")
    }
}

 fun goToMainActivity() {
    var intents = Intent (this,CheckAuthenticate::class.java)
    intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intents)
    finish()
}

 fun displayMessage(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    when(p0?.id){
        R.id.logout_text ->{
            logout()
        }
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

}

What should i do to make it work? How should i properly handle this exception so that my application does not crash? Please help anyone...

Comment: You are using Firebase Database and you might some rules applied that is restricting you from accessing it rr you have not logged in to firebase.

Comment: If you don't care about the exception, use `emitter.tryOnError` in this particular case. However, the "Permission denied" sounds like an application logic error worth investigating.

Comment: @chandil03 I am successfully logged in to Firebase and i getting this exception when i trying to logout ,, clearing all tasks and creating new tasks for my activities..

Comment: @Mattwalk Then i guess you are logging our user first and then accessing "Users" child. Do whatever operation you want to do first and then log out when operations are complete. Make sure that your all operation has completed and then log out.

Comment: @chandil03 all operations are working successfully , also i am clearing my composite disposable in onStop method..I ain't calling emitter.onComplete() after emitter.onNext() because i ain't able to fetch all users if i do that way..

Comment: @Mattwalk can you post all the code that is related to above given code, like logout code and its flow?

Comment: @chandil03 I added Acount settings class where i am doing logout user. You can check now .

Comment: @Mattwalk When are you accessing Users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle UndeliverableException. Add to your Application onCreate():

```
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(error -> {
        //Log error or just ignore it
    });
```